# Searching wiki URLs using Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax

I am trying to index and search a wiki on our intranet using Solr.  I have it more-or-less working using edismax but I'm having trouble getting main topic pages to show up first in the search results.  For example, suppose I have some URLs in the database:

```
http://whizbang.com/wiki/Foo/Bar
http://whizbang.com/wiki/Foo/Bar/One
http://whizbang.com/wiki/Foo/Bar/Two
http://whizbang.com/wiki/Foo/Bar/Two/Two_point_one
```

I would like to be able to search for "foo bar" and have the first link returned as the top result because it is the main page for that particular topic in the wiki.  I've tried boosting the title and URL field in the search but the fieldNorm value for the document keeps affecting the scores such that sub-pages score higher.  In one particular case, the main topic page shows up on the 2nd results page.

Is there a way to make the First URL score significantly higher than the sub categories so that it shows up in the top-5 search results?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach to try:

1. Create a copyField with your url
2. Extract path only (so, no host, no wiki)
3. Split on / and maybe space
4. Lowercase
5. Boost on phrase or bigram or something similar.

If you have a lot of levels, maybe you want a multivalued field, with different depth (starting from the end) getting separate entries. That way a perfect match will get better value. Here, you should start experimenting with your real searches.

Comment: Can this be accomplished using the standard tokenizers/filters or would I need to do some Java coding and create my own?

Comment: This should be doable with standard collection. Maybe regex for part 2, though I think there were things for that too. Have a read through the defined chains in default example. It shows quite a number of variations.

Comment: Alex - you are correct; I think that using the regex filters will help.  I also found that adding the title and URL fields the edismax "pf" variable ([Phrase Fields"](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#pf_.28Phrase_Fields.29)) helped.